# Trying to open a php file in background using ajax on link click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to open a php file in the background on a link click instead of showing the user that link to the php file.

I realize the only way to do this is with ajax.

But it is not working, instead of opening the new php page in background instead nothing happens, the php code does not execute.

my javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a#run-php-script').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php?addId=<?php echo $add->id); ?>'
        });
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

my html

```
<a id="run-php-script" href="#">clickit</a>
```

Please note that my php script works perfectly when I put the php link into the html href tag. But problem with that is that it reveals to the user my php file url and I won't want the user to see it nor do i want it to open in a new tab if at all possible but instead in the background.

I also tried it with `GET` instead of `POST`, still not working.

Please help thanks

---

**update --** per user request i have changed it to a button. also I had forgotten to wrap the tags. but still it doesn't work.

new js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#run-php-script').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php?addId=<?php echo $add->id); ?>',
        success: function(){
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('failure');
        }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

new html

```
<input id="run-php-script" type="button" name="someBtn" value="clickit" />
```

when i click the button still nothing happens. php page does not open in background.

i added success code into the script above. but even though it says "success" popup, still the actual php page doesn't open in the background and execute, just nothing happens.

please help thanks

Comment: "it reveals to the user my php file url and I won't want the user to see it " - if you're making a request to a file regardless of whether that ends up in the browser's location bar, it's trivial to find out what the url to your script is, for instance by using the network inspection tab in a browser's developer tools.

Comment: If you don't want to open the page then why to use link <a> tag? Use a button instead and on click send ajax. I think it should suffice.

Comment: @dymos maybe so, but 99% of users would not know how to hack out the url as you mentioned including myself

Comment: @TechBreak I am fine with using a button, it does not have to be a link. It was a link originally and I am trying to change it to the ajax request. You could post your suggestion.

Comment: @server1257 i have added snippet, please check if that works? This will avoid link tag behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I wasn't able to get it working with ajax, I was able to get it working another way. Instead of using ajax I turned the link/input into a button and submitted it as a form. I was able to populate it and it works!! Now the user COULD extrapolate the URL but only if they know what they are doing. There is no longer any full url, instead the url is obfuscated in a way, so that the user won't be able to see the url like they could when it was a link.

---

So here is my final working code. I tested it hard and finally have a solution!

(no javascript or ajax was used, just a standard form element)

html

```
<form action="http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="addId" value="<?php echo $add->id); ?>">clickit</button>
</form>
```

---

What this does is a few things.

1. `name=`
   what this does is add that name value after the `?`. so for example by putting the name value `addId` it will add this to the url: `?addId=`
2. `value=`
   now for the value, this is the variable that decides what to append on the end. so i fetched the value I needed and inserted the php code into the `value` field.

So for example say that my `$add->id` for this page was `999`. This would result in `999` being appended afterward like this: `?addId=999`.

3. you needed it to be a button, because if it was input then the text would be the name of the value, so instead of "`clickit`" for the button text, it would read "`999`", and you don't want that so make it a button not an input.

---

What is even better about this simple solution is that it does everything I want:

a) it does not open any new page

b) it runs the php code in the background

c) the user can't see the link. Yes if they know html coding they can put together the link but most people won't know that which is perfect for my usage.

---

So what happens when I click the button is this:

a) it combines the string and value and concatenates it to the url

b) it executes the php file in the background, no new page

c) user can't ever see a full url

So in practice, this is what the html might look like to the user:

```
<form action="http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="addId" value="999">clickit</button>
</form>
```

And when user clicks the button it opens this php file in the background:

```
http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php?addId=999
```

but this link is not opened in any new window and it is done in the background so that user never sees that full link.

---

This makes for a great user experience. And also a degree of privacy.

IF your file is critical, this won't work for you because user is still able to put together the name and value to make the string to the url, but most users don't know this and is too complicated for most. But it is possible so if the data is sensitive then you should not use this method. Instead you shouldn't even be opening a php file in the first place, instead you should send everything in the background through the server entirely differently.

But if the data is not critical and it is ok if 1 out of 1,000,000 users or so thinks hard enough to put it together, that is OK, so then this button method will do what you want.

enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Two things going wrong here for you:

- The link has a `target="_blank"` attribute, so clicking on it will open up the href in a new tab, you should remove it.
- The event handler doesn't prevent the default action for the link

You should to add the preventDefault() call to the handler if you do not want the browser to handle the link at all

e.g.

```
$('a#run-php-script').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Comment: ok that solved issue 1, the new window. I will update my code. However, the php file does not execute on click.

Comment: i updated my question with your fix but it does not solve that the php page is not opening in background and executing.

Comment: Do you see an error in the console? You can also try to debug in the event handler with developer tools or with console.log() to verify you're getting in to that. Also check that `<?php echo $add->id); ?>` is actually rendered by PHP. If this is in a JS file, unless it is pre-parsed by PHP that will just send along junk as the `addId` param

Comment: also what do you mean when you say "opening in background and executing" - do you mean that it is requested via AJAX and something happens on the server or are you expecting something else to happen here?

Comment: The php file has a script inside and is supposed to execute. When it is just inserted into the href and opens in another page it executes the script normally. But I want to execute in background so that user cannot see the url to the php page, so that's why I am trying to do it with ajax.

Comment: That error doesn't look consistent with any of the code you've posted. Where does it come from? What do you do with the PHP script you load? Try to debug this by breaking on uncaught errors in chrome devtools.

Answer (score 1):

use Chrome devTools network tab to check if there is any form data been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Add a button instead of a link,

```
 <input id="run-php-script" type="button" name="someBtn" value="clickit" />
```

Register your click event on this button,

```
 $('button#run-php-script').click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://mywebsiteaa.com/myfile.php?addId=<?php echo $add->id); ?>'
    });        
});
```

Comment: i actually like it as a button better! But still if i click nothing happens.

Comment: @server1257 I hope you have $('button#run-php-script') and not $('a#run-php-script'). Also if your actual concern is addressed please accept my answer. Now you might have ajax issues.

Comment: i also changed `a#run-php-script` to `#run-php-script` since it's not an `a` anymore. But still nothing happens when i click it.

Comment: oh i also removed the `e` from `(e)` and also `e.preventDefault();` since there is no need to prevent defailt anymore. but still nothing happens when I click it.

Comment: Yes, remaining scripts we assume you have properly added

Comment: @server1257 you can accept my suggestion if it was helpful in solving your link issues you faced.

Comment: does your php received request? try echo otherwise you need to fix ajax call. Also your issue was link click and not the one you are facing now after solving the issue.

Comment: huh? what do you mean "php received request"? the thing you fixed was an error i did not not the real problem when is to open php file in background, all your fix does its prevent me from opening another page by accident also but doesn't fix the reason it isn't working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127977/discussion-between-techbreak-and-server1257).